# EJuiDateTimePicker value is not saved to database

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am using EJuiDateTimePicker extension for date and time picker in yii framework. I have downloaded EJuiDateTimePicker and placed under protected\extensions\jui

**Views:**

```
$this->widget(
                    'ext.jui.EJuiDateTimePicker',
                    array(
                        'model'     => $model,
                        'attribute' => 'todo_datetime',
                        'value' => $model->todo_datetime,
                        'options'   => array(
                            'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy',
                            'timeFormat' => 'hh:mm:ss',//'hh:mm tt' default
                        ),
                    )
                );
```

**action:**

```
if(isset($_POST['Todo']))
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Todo'];
                if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}
```

**Problem:**

The value of saved in database table is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 It's not taking the value of datetime picker.

**Edited:**

**Model Validation**

```
return array(
    array('todo_text, todo_datetime, priority, status', 'required'),
    array('priority, status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
    // The following rule is used by search().
    // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
    array('todo_text, todo_datetime, added_on, priority, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
);
```

Comment: Show us your model validation rules

Comment: And what is the date field in your db (datetime, timestamp, ...) ?

Comment: I have datetime as data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nothing strange, you should use the same date format in your widget and in your database, actually :

- in your widget : `dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss`
- in database : `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

You can deal with this common problem using getter/setter or beforeSave/afterFind, here is a **simple** example using getter/setter :

**In your model** :

```
public $dateTimeIncomeFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss';
public $dateTimeOutcomeFormat = 'dd-MM-yy H:mm:ss';

public function getDateTime()
{
    return Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format($this->dateTimeOutcomeFormat, CDateTimeParser::parse($this->todo_datetime, $this->dateTimeIncomeFormat));
}

public function setDateTime($datetime)
{
    $this->todo_datetime = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format($this->dateTimeIncomeFormat, CDateTimeParser::parse($datetime, $this->dateTimeOutcomeFormat));
}
```

This will create a `dateTime` virtual attribute that you can use in your widget.
Don't forget to add this attribute in your model validation rules.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/topics.i18n#date-and-time-formatting

Comment: I have correct datetime format in widget option                         'options'   => array(
                            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                            'timeFormat' => 'h:mm:ss',//'hh:mm tt' default
                        ),